# With the new Javadoc API, is it possible to update the javadoc comment by a custom doclet?

Tags: java, javadoc

In the [new Javadoc api](https://openjdk.org/jeps/221) `jdk.javadoc.doclet.*`, I cannot find a way to change the Javadoc comment. I want to change only few things in the comment and parameter method through a custom doclet. I do not want to change the whole process of generating HTML files that must remain.

I tried something like this, but it depends on the previous Javadoc API `com.sun.source.doctree.*`

```java
private void modifyJavadocComment(MethodDoc method, String newComment) 
{
    // Create a modified Javadoc comment and set it for the method
    String modifiedComment = "/**\n * " + newComment + "\n */";
    method.setRawCommentText(modifiedComment);
}
```

It seems that `setRawCommentText()` does not exist in the new javadoc API. Can you publish some tutorial how to do it in the new API if existing?